# Creating a Count down timer

Tags: objective-c, timer, clock

I'm creating a countdown timer in Xcodes with Obc C. I'm a newbie on this and need some assistance with my timer, it is going to count down from what ever time you enter.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
-(void) timerRun {
    secoundCount = secoundCount - 1;
    int minuts = secoundCount / 60;
    int seconds = secoundCount - (minuts * 60);


    NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d:%.2d", minuts, seconds];
    countdownlable.text = timerOutput;
```

This countdown works perfectly find as long as it's counting down from 99 minutes or less. 
I would like to had one more int for hours but when I do that something goes wrong and I get an error.

Could you please explain how I would add one more integer for "hours" to this counter

I've tried the following but it's not working:

```
-(void) timerRun {
    secoundCount = secondCount - 1;
    int hours = secondCount / 60;
    int minuts = secondCount / 60;
    int seconds = secondCount - (minuts * 60);


    NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1d:%2d:%.2d", hours, minuts, seconds];
    countdownlable.text = timerOutput;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to achieve this, for example using the "modulo" operator:

```
int tmp = secondCount;
int seconds = tmp % 60;
tmp /= 60;
int minutes = tmp % 60;
tmp /= 60;
int hours = tmp;

NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
```

This method has the advantage that you can easily extend it to larger time intervals,
for example:

```
int tmp = secondCount;
int seconds = tmp % 60;
tmp /= 60;
int minutes = tmp % 60;
tmp /= 60;
int hours = tmp % 24;
tmp /= 24;
int days = tmp;
```

*Remark:* Instead of decrementing the remaining time by one second in the timer callback
function, it might be more precise to *compute* it like

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
secondCount = [destinationTime timeIntervalSinceDate:now];
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make count for the minuts.

i think your mistake is logical error

because Hour is not equal to second count / 60

```
int hours = minutsCount / 60;
```

and you can use NSTimer

you will find it here

[How do i create a countdown timer in xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504341/how-do-i-create-a-countdown-timer-in-xcode-4-5)